# Should I add a memory barrier in FIFO enqueue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fifo, memory-barriers

I'm implementing a non-locking FIFO using a linked list.

The `Enqueue` of the FIFO is basically:

```
void Enqueue(CNode node)
{
  m_tail->m_next = node;

  // Do I need a memory barrier here?

  m_tail = node;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any need to add a memory barrier if it's single threaded(i.e., Could compiler/processor rearrange the order of the two lines above?). And what if it's multi-threaded(i.e., as simple as single read single writer case)?

**Edit**: According to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency#Anti-dependency), this is a case of *data anti-dependency* and statements should not be reordered. So I assume CPU should always access memory in the given order. Is that right?

Comment: I have a suspicion that your code already isn't thread safe. What happens when your thread is suspended for an arbitrary amount of time between those two statements? Is it safe for another thread to come in and overwrite your work? Is one half meaningful without the other? A lock-free list update generally has a CAS loop somewhere.

Comment: @GManNickG, I mentioned that as to multithreaded, I mean "single reader single writer".

Comment: @EricZ: My point still stands. Is the state between the statements okay to be consumed?

Comment: @GManNickG, If you mean that a reader could be updating the same node at the same time, no, that's not my concern. I add a sentinel node to prevent reader, writer accessing the same node simultaneously. But, anyway, my concern is when will the compiler/CPU reorder those two statments, if they'll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler must not rearrange your m_tail and m_tail->next assignment such that m_tail is assigned with node before m_tail->next has been set. However, for a multi-threaded solution, you could have to worry about:

```
temp = m_tail;
m_tail = node;
temp->next = node;
node->next = NULL;
```

With a memory barrier, the compiler and/or the processor must complete the `m_tail->next = node;` (and `node->next = NULL;`) before it writes the `m_tail = node;`. Whether this is sufficent to guarantee correct execution is not certain, it depends a bit on what the code reading at the other end does.

Comment: Even if the compiler doesn't re-arrange the order of the two assignments, is there a guarantee that other threads _see_ the assignments made in that order? They may be running on separate cores, with their local caches not updated in the same order etc. Or can that possibility be excluded somehow?

Comment: Data dependency will acquire CPU commit memory access in the order. Is that true?

Comment: Modern compilers and modern CPU's do things in an order that "makes sense to them". Processors will, for example, execute instructions out of order, because of how data is fetched from memory. Compile may see that using registers in a different way makes the code more efficient. I admit that it's not VERY common to see something like my example above, but depending on what's in what register (and how many registers are "free"), the compiler may decide to rearrange stores and loads to make the register usage better. Consider that the constructor for CNode and Enqueue are inlined...